# Pandas groupby groups to return values rather than indicies

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   0       1            2
63.0    66.0        119.0
78.0    253.0       157.0
78.0    383.0       157.0
63.0    405.0       119.0
120.0   830.0       260.0
...     ...     ...
80.0    30434914.0  160.0
112.0   30434960.0  240.0
80.0    30435059.0  160.0
98.0    30435079.0  213.0
80.0    30435119.0  160.0
```

I've created a groupby object to group the items in column 1 by the items in column 2:

```
dx = df.groupby(df[2])[1]
```

Upon calling dx.groups I get a dictionary with the values of column 2 as keys and the indices of column 1 as values. However, I would like to get the values of column 1 rather than the indices. One way I was able to do this was by writing the below dictionary comprehension:

```
{group:np.array(dx.get_group(group)) for group in dx.groups}
```

Is there way to do this with a Pandas method rather than having to write a dictionary comprehension?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
dx.apply(list)
```

or

```
dx.apply(np.array)
```

to get values in a `pandas.Series`. So the result will be:

```
2
119.0     [66.0, 405.0]
157.0    [253.0, 383.0]
260.0           [830.0]
```

To reset index name, you can

```
s = dx.apply(np.array)
s.index.name = None
```

which produces

```
119.0     [66.0, 405.0]
157.0    [253.0, 383.0]
260.0           [830.0]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: You're welcome. If you like the answer, could you accept it as a 'accepted answer'?